# Default compiler optimization flag used by LibraryLink (CreateLibrary)?

Tags: performance-tuning, librarylink, c++, ccompilerdriver

What's the default optimization level (e.g. -O2, -O3) used by the function CreateLibrary, which invokes the system compiler to compile C/C++ code for use in LibraryLink?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on the specific compiler driver that is being used.

The easiest way to get not only the compiler options, but the entire compilation command is to add `"ShellCommandFunction" -> Print` to [`CreateLibrary`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCompilerDriver/ref/CreateLibrary.html) (or whichever function you used to compile).